# how to update view of window manager on push notification android

Tags: android, window, android-windowmanager

i have view which is gone in layout . i want  to update view of window manager like (Visible) when push comes .I tried various things but nothing happend.

Comment: You should post your code so that we could see what is missing

Comment: what push notification service you are using? paste your message handler..class code